# How to push custom attribute to eloquent object (model) after fetch?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have custom model `User` and I want push custom attribute to model after fetching data. How I can do it?

I know what before fetching we can add custom attibute like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['callable'];

    public function getCallableAttribute()
    {
        $callable = $this->getMeta('phone') ? true : false;
        return $callable;
    }
}
```

But how do it after fetching data, for example after:

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

And now how append custom attribute to fetched `User` object data?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [Laravel Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for that

E.g.

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the user's full name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
     public function getFullNameAttribute()
     {
        return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
     }
}
```

Then you can access Accessors like this:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
$firstName = $user->first_name; // In studly Case
$firstName = $user->full_name; // In studly Case
```

You can read more about Laravel Accessors here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: As said in laravel documentation  _"The accessor will automatically be called by Eloquent when attempting to retrieve the value of the first_name attribute"_. Accessors will work with fields, which **defined in database table**. And as said in my question title _"How to push custom attribute to eloquent object (model) after fetch?"_ I want add custom attribute to `eloquent` object custom attribute **AFTER FETCH** and not before. Please read question again. @AkshayKhale